# Ошибка в запросе c 3-мя таблицами

Tags: php, mysql

При отправке данного запроса:

```
$query = mysql_query(
'SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.title,
  t1.autor,
  t1.date,
  t1.category,
  t1.short_story, 
  t1.alt_name,
  t2.images,
  t2.news_id,
  t3.id,
  t3.alt_name AS t3_alt_name,
FROM
  dle_post AS t1, dle_images AS t2, dle_category AS t3
WHERE
  t1.id = t2.news_id AND t1.category = t3.id
ORDER BY date DESC') or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

Выдает вот такую ошибку:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'FROM dle_post AS t1, dle_images AS t2, dle_category AS t3
>   WHERE t1.id = t2' at line 3

Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: `t3.alt_name AS t3_alt_name, FROM` - запятая перед `FROM` не нужны. И научитесь джойны делать, так как у вас точно не годится

Comment: учту, спасибо!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для выбора из нескольких таблиц, нужно использовать джоины. попробуй что-то из такого рода.

```
$query = mysql_query(
'SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.title,
  t1.autor,
  t1.date,
  t1.category,
  t1.short_story, 
  t1.alt_name,
  t2.images,
  t2.news_id,
  t3.id,
  t3.alt_name AS t3_alt_name
FROM
  dle_post AS t1
INNER JOIN dle_images AS t2
    ON t1.id = t2.news_id
INNER JOIN dle_category AS t3
    ON t1.category = t3.id
WHERE
  t1.id = твой id новости
ORDER BY date DESC') or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Кстати не то что бы join особо нужны. в MySQL запятая в from синоним предложений join и inner join, с переносом условий из ON в where.

Comment: @Mike, ON - фильтрация во время выборки из конкретной таблицы, WHERE - когда уже получили нужные строки. На INNER JOIN это не так заметно как на LEFT JOIN, но все равно - лучше явно контролировать что и как подключаем, чем потом городить условия в WHERE (ON все-таки пропустить труднее, чем условие в WHERE)

Comment: @BOPOH Ну это по стандартам так, только вот СУБД не спешат этих стандартов придерживаться. План выполнения не меняется (по крайней мере для MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL). На счет наглядности ... ну, дело привычки. Хотя соглашусь, явное указание намерений (ON) ведет к дисциплине. (И жуткому загромождению, когда в запросе  таблиц 20)

Answer (score 0):

Собственно сообщение об ошибке вам показывает точку, откуда анализатор не может разобрать запрос. Как правило, проблема непосредственно начиная с этой точки или перед ней, в данном случае перед FROM лишняя запятая.